# How to find all positive integer solutions of a Diophantine equation?

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Here is the equation

$$
    6a+9b+20c=16
$$
To solve this, i follow the below steps :

$\gcd(6,9)(2a+3b)+20c = 16$
let, $w = 2a+3b$
So, $3w+20c =16$
then, specific solution of $w = 112+20n$, $c = -16-3n$ ; where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

After that, 
$w = 2a+3b$
So, $2a+3b = 112+20n$, I need to solve this equ. To find the solution of $a$ and $b$.

Finally I got,
$$ 
A = -(112+20n)+3m \\
B = 112+20n-2m \\
C = -16-3n
$$

I tried to do above by Euclidean algorithm.

**Now, my question is, is it ok or the solving is right?
and how do i got the positive ans for $a,b,c$ ?
If there's any wrong in solving process , please explain me that.**

Comment: I didn't read your solution but it came to me that since the coefficient of $c$ is 20,  a, b, c, can not all be positive. If they were all positive integers, $a, b, c\geq 1$ which means, $6a+9b+20c \geq 35>20$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429727/find-all-the-solutions-of-6a9b20c-2?rq=1) for a solution (replace $16$ by $-2$).

Comment: @zxcvber The OP asked "how do i got the positive ans", which I think means "how can I get the solutions, in case the answer to solvability is positive". So we may be looking at integer solutions.

Comment: I have no better idea than to determine the solution over $\mathbb{Z}^3$ and then restricting to $(a,b,c) > 0$.

Comment: Have you inserted your solution into the original equation to verify it?

Comment: COMMENT.-It is clear that there are not positive solutions because $6\cdot1+9\cdot1+20\cdot1=35\gt16$ You can verify this another way taking the parametrics given by the identity $$6(-3s-10t-4)+9(2s)+20(3t+2)=16$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $6a + 9b + 20c = 16$ as the equation of a plane, in $a,b,c$.
Once that you know three points in it, with integer coordinates, ${\bf v}_{\bf 0},{\bf v}_{\bf 1},{\bf v}_{\bf 2} $, from ${\bf v}_{\bf 1}-{\bf v}_{\bf 0}$ and ${\bf v}_{\bf 2}-{\bf v}_{\bf 0}$ you can determine two vectors ${\bf u}_{\bf 1},{\bf u}_{\bf 2} $ having components with $gcd=1$.
Then all the solutions will be given by 
$$
{\bf v} = {\bf v}_{\bf 0}  + n\,{\bf u}_{\bf 1}  + m\,{\bf u}_2 \quad \left| {\;{\rm integers}\;n,m} \right.
$$
The ${\bf u}$ vectors can be more easily determined considering the parallel plane through the origin (the "homogeneous" solution).
Therefore consider
$$
6a + 9b + 20c = 0
$$
here ${\bf v}_0  = \left( {0,0,0} \right)$ and ${\bf u}_{\bf 1}  = \left( {3, - 2,0} \right)\quad {\bf u}_{\bf 2}  = \left( {10,0, - 3} \right)$ follow immediately by putting one of the variables at zero.
Then we can easily find a "particular" solution by putting, e.g., $b=0$ and achieving
$$
6a + 9b + 20c = 16\quad  \to \quad 6a + 0 + 20c = 16\quad  \to \quad 3a + 0 + 10c = 8\quad \to \quad {\bf v}_{\bf p}  = \left( {6,0, - 1} \right)
$$
The solution is therefore
${\bf v} = {\bf v}_{\bf p}  + n\,{\bf u}_{\bf 1}  + m\,{\bf u}_2\quad$ that is: $\quad
\left\{ \matrix{
  a = 6 + 3n + 10m \hfill \cr 
  b =  - 2n \hfill \cr 
  c =  - 1 - 3m \hfill \cr}  \right.$
In fact: $\quad16 = 6a + 9b + 20c = 16 + 0n + 0m$